# Count shared values

Tags: r, dataframe

## Problem

I have a data frame (df), who looks like this:

```
V1      V2
a1      a4
a1      a5
a2      a4
a2      a6
a3      a4
a4      a5 
a2      a5
```

For each pair of unique values in V1, I want to calculate the number of values they share in V2.

For example, consider `a1` and `a2` in V1. They both have `a4` and `a5` in V2. Thus, for the `a1`-`a2` pair, the result is `2` shared observations (in column `W3`). And so on for all other pairs which share values:

```
W1    W2    W3
a1    a2    2
a1    a3    1
a1    a4    1
a1    a3    1
a2    a3    1
```

Some idea how can I do it?

Comment: a2 and a4 both have a5 in V2, but they are not in result. a1 and a3 have two rows. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just join `df` onto itself by V2 column, count the cooccurrence of V1 items and filter the result, so that W1 < W2, since it is symmetrical anyway...

```
library(solar)
library(stringr)

result <- df %>%
  left_join(df, by = "V2") %>%
  count(W1 = V1.x, W2 = V1.y, name = "W3") %>%
  filter(W1 < W2)
```

Comment: dude this is amazing,a base R equivalent is `subset(data.frame(table(subset(merge(df, df, by="V2"), V1.x<V1.y)[-1])), Freq > 0)`

Answer (score 3):

```
tcrossprod(table(d))
#    V1
# V1   a1 a2 a3 a4
#   a1  2  2  1  1
#   a2  2  3  1  1
#   a3  1  1  1  0
#   a4  1  1  0  1
```

If desired, grab the upper (or lower) triangle, e.g.

```
ix = which(upper.tri(m), arr.ind = TRUE)
data.frame(v1 = dimnames(m)[[1]][ix[, 1]], v2 = dimnames(m)[[2]][ix[, 2]], n = m[ix])
```

---

Or treat as a graph problem:

```
library(igraph)
g = graph_from_data_frame(d)
bibcoupling(g)
#    a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6
# a1  0  2  1  1  0  0
# a2  2  0  1  1  0  0
# a3  1  1  0  0  0  0
# a4  1  1  0  0  0  0
# a5  0  0  0  0  0  0
# a6  0  0  0  0  0  0


plot(g)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `combn`.  We `split` the 'V2' by 'V1' column, then get the `combn`atios of pairwise elements of `list` to return the `length` of `intersect`ing elements, `name` the `list` elements with the pairwise concatenation of names of 'lst1', `stack` it to a two column data.frame, `separate` the concatenated column into two and `rename` if needed

```
lst1 <- split(df1$V2, df1$V1)
outlst <- combn(lst1, 2, FUN = function(x) 
         length(Reduce(intersect, x)), simplify = FALSE) 
names(outlst) <- combn(names(lst1), 2, FUN = paste, collapse = "_")

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
subset(stack(outlst), values >0)[2:1] %>% 
    separate(ind, into = c('W1', 'W2')) %>% 
    rename(W3 = values)
#  W1 W2 W3
#1 a1 a2  2
#2 a1 a3  1
#3 a1 a4  1
#4 a2 a3  1
#5 a2 a4  1
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(V2) %>%
   summarise(V1 = if(n() > 1) combn(V1, 2, FUN = paste, collapse='_') 
         else NA_character_) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   filter(!is.na(V1)) %>%
   separate(V1, into = c('W1', 'W2')) %>% 
   count(W1, W2)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  W1    W2        n
#  <chr> <chr> <int>
#1 a1    a2        2
#2 a1    a3        1
#3 a1    a4        1
#4 a2    a3        1
#5 a4    a2        1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("a1", "a1", "a2", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a2"
), V2 = c("a4", "a5", "a4", "a6", "a4", "a5", "a5")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R you could do:

```
a <- table(unlist(aggregate(.~V2, df, 
         function(x)if(length(x)>1) combn(x, 2, paste, collapse = " "))[,2]))
read.table(text=paste(names(a),a))
  V1 V2 V3
1 a1 a2  2
2 a1 a3  1
3 a1 a4  1
4 a2 a3  1
5 a4 a2  1
```